# How do I check for a specific IP Address, and then change it if it does not exist?

Tags: powershell, ip-address

I am trying to test for a specific IP Address and then change it if it is not there in Powershell.

I am not sure what is wrong with my code:

```
if($wmi.ipaddress -ne "10.0.0.15") {$wmi = Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -filter "ipenabled ='true'"
                                       $wmi.EnableStatic("10.0.0.15", "255.255.255.0")
                                       $wmi.SetGateways("10.0.0.1", 1)
                                       $wmi.SetDNSServerSearchOrder("127.1.1.12")}
```

Comment: What OS are you running?  Windows 8/2012r2 have better methods for managing network config.

Comment: How does it behave - any errors? Changing some settings but not others? Does the script block run at all (use `Write-Host` in it)?

Comment: I am using Windows 7.  I do not know a lot about Powershell but the address is definitely not changing.

Comment: @Serussel How are you creating **$wmi** in the first place? And why is `$wmi = Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -filter "ipenabled ='true'"` in the **if** statement's scriptblock? Did you intend for that line to come *before* the **if**?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of problems.

1. There's no guarantee that **$wmi** is a single object, so attempting to invoke methods on it is a leap of faith that your filter will only match one NIC. If there's more than one NIC that has an IP address, **Get-WmiObject** will return an array of objects representing the NICs. That can have one of two effects:

   - In PowerShell versions 1 and 2, **$wmi.ipaddress** will be null, and all your method invocations will fail, because those are not valid methods of array objects.
   - In PowerShell versions 3 and higher, **$wmi.ipaddress** will be an array of all the IP addresses on all of the NICs in the array. Even worse, your method invocations will be applied to each object in the array, which means you're trying to configure the same IP address for multiple NICs.
2. As TessellatingHeckler already mentioned, the **IPAddress** property is an array. If you provide an array as the left operand of a comparison operator, PowerShell returns an array of all elements that match (e.g. `('a', 'b', 'c', 'd') -ne 'c'` returns an array of the strings `a`, `b`, and `d`).

   So, *IF* **$wmi** is a single object, your test condition `($wmi.ipaddress -ne "10.0.0.15")` will be true if the NIC has any IP addresses other than 10.0.0.15. If none of your NICs have multiple IP addresses, then this condition *will* work to determine whether the NIC doesn't have that IP address, but in a roundabout manner—because the return value of the comparison is an empty array, which converts to a False boolean value.

   On the other hand, if a NIC has the IP address 10.0.0.15 and any other IP address(es), then the condition will return True, because the comparison will return an array of the other IP address(es).

   The test condition in TessellatingHeckler's answer,

   ```
   ($wmi.IPAddress -notcontains "10.0.0.15")
   ```

   will work, or the following will also work

   ```
   (! ($wmi.IPAddress -eq "10.0.0.15"))
   ```

   because it will only be False if the **IPAddress** array includes 10.0.0.15.

However, neither of the test conditions in **2.** will help you unless you address the issue in **1.**. In both cases the condition will return False if *any* of the NICs have the IP address 10.0.0.15, which actually is probably what you *do* want, but then you're going to be trying to set the same IP address on multiple NICs.

See the last part [this answer I posted at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20085537/1248365) for suggestions on how to ensure that you're getting only one object from `Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration`. However, that doesn't ensure that you'll be selecting the *right* NIC. That's not something I could tell you how to do, because I don't know by what criteria you want to determine which NIC will be assigned the desired IP address if there are multiple NIC where **IPEnabled** is true.

One final thought: Are you by any chance trying to execute this script on a remote computer? If so, see [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17822916/1248365) I provided to someone who was having trouble with a script that was trying to use a PowerShell WMI object to change the IP configuration on a remote computer.

Answer (score 1):

IPAddress in a Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration object is a string *array*, not a string - so you might need to test if the IP address is not in the array, instead of if it doesn't equal the array:

```
if ($wmi.IPAddress -notcontains "10.0.0.15") { ... }
```

Comment: His test condition actually *will* work unless he has a NIC with that IP address *and* other ones, because he's filtering for NICs that have IP addresses, and `($wmi.ipaddress -ne "10.0.0.15")` will return True if the NIC has an IP address but not 10.0.0.15. But you're right that **IPAddress** is an array property, and **-ne** is not the right way to test this. `(! ($wmi.IPAddress -eq "10.0.0.15"))` would also work. However, I think the real issue here is that the filter he's using can match multiple NICs and return an array of objects, and that *will* happen on most modern computers.

Comment: @AdiInbar his test condition happens before he uses the filter, we don't see where the original `$wmi` object is created or how.

Comment: I'm inferring that it's being created somewhere earlier in the script with **gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration**. Otherwise the code doesn't make any sense, and the condition would always be True regardless of whether you use **-ne** or **-notcontains**, because **$wmi.ipaddress** would be null. But that does beg the question, is he using the same filter to define **$wmi** in the first place? In fact, it seems strangely out of place to define **$wmi** in the body of the **if** statement at all. I wonder if that's a copy/paste error and that line was supposed to be before the **if**?